# Postgresql LIMIT on SELECT TABLE disregarding joins to force not accidentally chopping multirow entities from being accidentally chopped

Tags: postgresql

So I have a SQL statement that has several 1 to Many relationships and thus throwing a LIMIT at the end chops off the joined pieces leaving me with potentially incomplete entities at the end of the limit.

Is there a way to limit the select table disregarding how many rows are joined so that I can make sure that I am always getting the full entity.

This is mainly used for ETL so it goes over a large chunk X number of entities at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM (SELECT * FROM first_table LIMIT 1000) a
   JOIN second_table b
      ON (a.id = b.a_id);
```